# Gazebo simulation automation

Tags: gazebo

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Hi,

I want to run gazebo simulations automatically over night. I am not sure where to start. The idea is, that a robot executes a specific mission. Eventually I would like a report or snapshots of checkpoints or a report.

Is there some support from gazebo or some kind of framework / plugins to help?
Maybe someone has had a similar challange?

BR

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/21217/gazebo-simulation-automation/) by [Eisenhorn](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/545/eisenhorn/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 43 on 2018-11-28

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [azeey](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/6889/azeey/) on 2018-11-28**:
Not really frameworks, but the ServerFixture and RenderFixture classes might be useful. They are used in Gazebo for testing.

http://osrf-distributions.s3.amazonaws.com/gazebo/api/dev/classgazebo_1_1ServerFixture.html,
http://osrf-distributions.s3.amazonaws.com/gazebo/api/dev/classgazebo_1_1RenderingFixture.html

**Comment by [Eisenhorn](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/545/eisenhorn/) on 2018-11-29**:
Thanks for your reply @azeey. Is there maybe a tutorial or demo implementation on how this classes are used best?

**Comment by [tahsinkose](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/6505/tahsinkose/) on 2019-06-21**:
I wonder, whether the OP have found a solution for this. I have the exact same use case and don't want to reinvent the wheel.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

In the end I wrote a pyhton test script using the actionlib.SimpleActionClient (http://wiki.ros.org/actionlib_tutorials/Tutorials/Writing%20a%20Simple%20Action%20Client%20%28Python%29)  interface. You can then create a json file with all your goals/actions.

---

Originally posted by [Eisenhorn](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/545/eisenhorn/) with karma: 43 on 2019-09-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

The [ServerFixture](http://osrf-distributions.s3.amazonaws.com/gazebo/api/dev/classgazebo_1_1ServerFixture.html)  and [RenderFixture](http://osrf-distributions.s3.amazonaws.com/gazebo/api/dev/classgazebo_1_1RenderingFixture.html) classes might be useful for automating simulations. I don't know of any tutorial that covers how to use the classes, but most of the [tests](https://bitbucket.org/osrf/gazebo/src/f4e51e8f64001beda70615ab8982a7d5a4e65b18/test/integration/?at=default) in gazebo use them. [Here](https://bitbucket.org/osrf/gazebo/src/f4e51e8f64001beda70615ab8982a7d5a4e65b18/test/integration/pr2.cc?at=default&fileviewer=file-view-default#pr2.cc-33) is an example of a test that spawns a PR2 and saves some pictures from its camera.

If you are manually running the simulation but want an output at the end of the simulation, you might be able to use [world](http://gazebosim.org/tutorials?tut=plugins_world&cat=write_plugin) or [system](http://gazebosim.org/tutorials?tut=system_plugin&cat=write_plugin) plugins, which are more accessible and have [tutorials](http://gazebosim.org/tutorials?cat=write_plugin).

---

Originally posted by [azeey](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/6889/azeey/) with karma: 704 on 2018-11-29

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [chapulina](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/1019/chapulina/) on 2018-11-29**:
For an example outside of Gazebo, you may want to look at gazebo_ros_pkgs tests on the ROS 2 branch, for example: https://github.com/ros-simulation/gazebo_ros_pkgs/blob/ros2/gazebo_plugins/test/test_gazebo_ros_diff_drive.cpp